# Selection mode like Google Android Mail

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an android app which presents list of items with icons.

- icon1 - ItemName1
- icon2 - ItemName2
- icon3 - ItemName3

Like in latest gmail app when we long press on an item the icon displays tick mark indicating item is selected.

There could be one way that I have two icons (one normal and other with tick mark) and i can replace the icon on long press.

Is this correct approach or could there be a better option or some library for it from google ?

Regards

Comment: How would your users know they need to long press to select? A tickbox would be much easier to see or maybe an imagebutton that changes it's image on select.

Comment: Hi,  Looking at all the apps from google now days Gmail, Drive etc.. This has become a common notion. In our usability tests also, people were using long press action more (maybe because they use gmail all the time)... I will check this image button. On image button can we animation also like gmail all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple. Found by navigating through stackoverflow.

1. For the icon put an imageview or imageviewbutton. Put a onClicklistener on it.
2. On click change the source of the imageview or imageviebutton to a image with selection indicator. You can also put an animation to make the image transition appear more smooth.

Regards, Ashwani Kr Sharma